# ¿Qué hacer con las migraciones antiguas?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, migration

Buen día!

Inicio esta pregunta, porque, hace ya tiempo que vengo trabajando con **Entity Framework 6** en ASP MVC 5,

Estoy trabajando con la metodología **Code First** y a lo largo del desarrollo han surgido muchos cambios en lo planeado originalmente, por lo que he tenido que ir agregando nuevas migraciones para actualizar la base de datos.

El asunto, es que en este momento, tengo una carpeta `Migrations` con una cantidad muy elevada de clases.

Logicamente, las últimas migraciones, es de vital importancia guardarlas ante cualquier fallo, pero, las migraciones antiguas, deben ser eliminadas?

¿Qué se debe hacer con los archivos `.cs` de cada una de las migraciones?

Espero se interprete bien la duda!

Saludos!

Comment: que tipo de sistema es?? pq tal vez, las migraciones antiguas se puedan archivar (ya que dudo que vayas a instalar la pagina de cero de vuelta)

Comment: Es un sistema de base de datos para transformadores, a muy grandes rasgos es un abm bastante complejo, mi duda iba un poco hacia el lado de en qué podía perjudicarme sacar esas migraciones del proyecto

Comment: Y si instalas de cero no se correrian.. pero una instalacion de cero ya deberia tener la base al dia de la fecha, sin migraciones...

Comment: Una cosa que puedes hacer si tienes bien definidos los mapeos de cada una de las tablas, es eliminar los archivos de las migraciones y el snapshot y crear una migración de cero. Esto solo si no tienes todavía en producción la base de datos. Sino te recomiendo que sigas con esa estructura. Finalmente son solo archivos que te muestran el historico de las migraciones.